# How to get rid of this poles?

Tags: modeling, topology, knife-tool, distort

[image]

How do i get rid of this pole? I tried to redirect edge flow using the knife but it distorts the curved surface. Is there a way around this?

[image]

This is the shape I'm trying to model.

Comment: why do you want to get rid of it?

Comment: @moonboots I just want to avoid this pinching https://i.imgur.com/GObewuR.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used a topology similar to yours and it seems to work fine with almost no artifacts. I just used and applied a *Shrinkwrap* modifier with a cylinder of the same radius as *Target* in order to correct the topology a bit and make it stick to a nice cylinder shape:

[image]

Comment: Shrinkwrap did the trick. Now it's perfect :D thank you
https://i.imgur.com/FCoYzNL.png