# Hole in cylinder Topology

Tags: modeling, topology, subdivision-surface

I'm attempting to cut a neat hole in a cylinder using minimal topology. I've used an octagon for both the cylinder and the hole. On applying the subdivision surface modifier, the region near the hole curves out a bit intersecting with parts of other objects which isn't supposed to happen with a perfect cylindrical surface. How may I correct it?

[image: side view]
[image: front view]

Comment: maybe try this method: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194716/how-to-get-rid-of-this-poles/194719#194719 ... it consists on using another cylinder as target of a shrinkwrap, it allows you to correct the shape of your cylinder. If it still doesn't work, please share your file

Comment: @moonboots Thanks! Yes that would work. But the required levels of subdivision has to be applied prior. Bending a fully subdivided plane would be another method which I actually did. But obviously has the same requirement as the former.

Answer (score -1):

When you create a low poly cylinder and then add a subsurf it creates a high poly cylinder but with a smaller diameter because the surface will be inscribed into the low poly cylinder's volume.

You have to push inside a bit the loop of your hole:
[image]